# Android Database: Dynamic Table Name Creation

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is it possible to create a database table name from user input. All of the tutorials I have seen have had the table name pre-created before the app is actually ran. Ideally, I would like to pass a String to the onCreate method (that is called to first create the DB table) and use that string as the table name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this to create the first table, but here is what I use to create new tables. The first table is mostly empty and I remove it from my listview list of tables. `loc` is the string I pass in. I'm in the process of switching it to a ContentProvider though

```
public long addTable(String loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + loc + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_2TBL
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ONE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_TWO + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_2TBL, loc);
    return ourDatabase.insert(loc, null, cv);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that Database will be created when you make Object of DatbaseClass.

You can Create object when you have got the String Name.

Then You can Pass it into a function as Bill Gary has Done in his Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use `onCreate()`method to create a second table.Because  it is called only when the Database is created & You will not be able to insert any String As Argument. You Can create a new method to do this.

the Method may look something like this,

```
    public void AddDesiredTable(String TableNmae){
    /*At first you will need a Database object.Lets create it.*/
    SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();

    /*then call 'execSQL()' on it. Don't forget about using TableName Variable as tablename.*/
    ourDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableNmae+ " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_2TBL
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ONE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_TWO + " TEXT NOT NULL);")
    }
```